# Setting absolute path does not work in Go for kubeconfig

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

I am making a call to kubectl from with a Go module like so:

```golang
getNsCmd := cmd.NewCmd("kubectl", "--kubeconfig", "~/.kube/<kube-config-file>", "get", "ns")
```

It works if I set the path like this:

```golang
getNsCmd := cmd.NewCmd("kubectl", "--kubeconfig", "../../../../.kube/<kube-config-file>", "get", "ns")
```

I am using the [Go cmd package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-cmd/cmd)

Currently this module lives in another repo and that's why it has to navigate up four levels. I figure this is because the command is running from the perspective of this file, but it doesn't seem like it should have to. If it's simple running it as a cli command the first one (I would think) should work.

When I run this command from the cli manually it works just fine:

```sh
$ kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/<kube-config-file> get ns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned I needed to grab the home directory environment var.
However I implemented it like this:

```
    homePath, _ := os.LookupEnv("HOME")

//

getNsCmd := cmd.NewCmd("kubectl", "--kubeconfig", homePath+"/.kube/<kube-config-file>", "get", "ns")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `~` as a shortcut is something [specific to bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).  `~` just grabs the user's $HOME directory, but does not work across all implementations of the shell.  This is something that can be used from the terminal but not always from code (it's not shell-independent).  However, go can also find the current user's home directory using `os.UserHomeDir()`.

https://pkg.go.dev/os#UserHomeDir

[Something like this should work](https://goplay.tools/snippet/w9vNpg4jRiH)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    homeDir, _ := os.UserHomeDir()

    fmt.Printf("%s/.kube/<kube-config-file>", homeDir)
}
```

Output: `/root/.kube/<kube-config-file>`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comment on the reply from OP due to my low reputation score :/ 

But I wanted to point out that, while this might not be a concern depending on your use case for the code, getting the HOME environment variable doesn't always work with Windows, which often uses `%USERPROFILE%`.  The `os.UserHomeDir` function is both shell and platform-agnostic, so will work cross-platform.

@Tariq

Answer (score 0):

Since the package you're using mentions that it wraps the Go's `os/exec` package, here is an excerpt from their [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec):

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the
> os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and
> does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions,
> pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells. The package
> behaves more like C's "exec" family of functions. To expand glob
> patterns, either call the shell directly, taking care to escape any
> dangerous input, or use the path/filepath package's Glob function. To
> expand environment variables, use package os's ExpandEnv.

So I think you would want to try something like this:

```
import "os"

getNsCmd := cmd.NewCmd("kubectl", "--kubeconfig", os.ExpandEnv("$HOME/.kube/<kube-config-file>"), "get", "ns")
```